# For some reason an else if isn't working

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I can't seem to get an else if to work right.

What I've been doing is writing a unit converter to try and teach myself the basics of programming, I'm kind of new to it. So new as to say this is actually my first working while loop. So I've been writing the code, and then doing as a friend who is somewhat more experienced at programming has told me to do. Which is separate said code out into methods. I used the VS2010 automatic method making thing for this, because I didn't know how to do it myself. The full source code in question is here http://pastebin.com/9mZPPtWr the problem bit is this one

`

```
      else if (type == "cups")

      {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of liters to be converted into cups.");
        amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(cupsTolitConverter.Convert(amount) + " cups to said number of liters.");

      }`
```

I entered cups into the console, and despite every other entry/imput working fine and the loop looping back to the selection bit each time, I can't seem to get that section of code to work. It just won't display, I've been working on it for an hour now, and I starting to think I'm missing something incredibly obvious, or something incredibly arcane. Also I have a lot of repeated code and I was wondering if there was a way to simplify that down to less repeats.

Thanks, and I hope that was readable and understandable. Even if my code probably isn't. Also I got the starting code(the top bit) from Accelerated C#. Will elaborate more on my question if needed.

Comment: Hit the case just fine when I ran the full posting.  Only issue was that the second writeline says "centimeters to said number of inches."  But you have it correct in the excerpt you posted above.

Comment: I dont have VS. But why dont you try debugging. It s time for you to learn debugging your code and see yourself what s happening. It might help you understand why and what is not working.

Comment: It worked fine for me, aside from as vossad noted the text added is "centimeters to said number of inches", but when looking through your code I saw a random line with just "done" which is going to prevent compiling. The error is in the `private static double MilesToFeet(UnitConverter milesToFeetConverter, ref int done)` method.

Comment: I would make two immediate changes: (1) use a `switch` block instead of repeated similar `else if`. (2) decide either to do everything inside the `switch` block, or do everything inside separate methods à la `Feet`, `Centimeters`. And perhaps (3) standardize your naming scheme. `centi` ≠ `cent` ≠ `Centimeters`. Once you've cleaned up all that, the error *might* be more easily found.

Comment: You also have extra curly braces that you don't need in your code. Removing those might help some confusion later on.

Comment: I want to add also that all these else if compare a string for equality against a lower case constant. These if will fail if you type for example "Cups"....

Comment: did't get your problem clearly. i just copy-pasted your code and its working. what exactly are you missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You have error in line 141. Delete that `done` word. I suggest it was just copy paste mistake. Second of all: Here you say your code is:

```
else if (type == "cups")

      {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of liters to be converted into cups.");
        amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(cupsTolitConverter.Convert(amount) + " cups to said number of liters.");

      }
```

But in the solution you gave link to there is:

```
else if(type == "cups")
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of liters to be converted into cups.");
                        amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine(cupsTolitConverter.Convert(amount) + " centimeters to said number of inches.");

                    }
```

I suggest it is just inattention. Your code work fine, just replace

```
Console.WriteLine(cupsTolitConverter.Convert(amount) + " centimeters to said number of inches.");
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(cupsTolitConverter.Convert(amount) + " cups to said number of liters.");
```

in your solution.

Talking about simplifying your code, and removing repeatings. Of course there is way to do that. That procedure is called code-refactoring. For example you wrote in your project:

```
...
else if(type == "grams")
                    {

                        amount = gramsToOunces(ozToGramsConverter, ref done);

                    }
...
```

Evaluation of `amount` you replaced to gramsToOunces() method. This is code refactoring too in some measure. You shoul take common parts of your code and look what they depending of. For example:

```
private static double MilesToFeet(UnitConverter milesToFeetConverter, ref int done)
        {

            double amount;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of miles to be converted to feet.");
            amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(milesToFeetConverter.Convert(amount) + " feet to said number of miles.");

            return amount;

        }
```

Every your convert method has such structure. In every method you do the same. You print the same instruction message... you declare the same amount variable and set it's value to console input... And you write almost the same information message after. All of this instead on N methods you have you can put in ONE method. First of all you should extend your converter class. Add two more string fields fields. `FromUnit` and `ToUnit`. Why??? Because you give converter instance as a parameter to your method. And you can use this instance for storing more information about this converter, and for creating information message after. For example:

```
public class UnitConverter
    {
        double ratio;
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public UnitConverter(double unitratio) { ratio = unitratio; }
        public double Convert(double unit) { return unit * ratio; }
    }
```

Than, when you create instance of converter, set appropriate values for these properties.

```
UnitConverter milesToFeetConverter = new UnitConverter(5280) { From = "miles" , To = "feet"};
```

Now  let's write a method which will be represantation of all of your already created methods (gramsToOunces, kilometersToMiles and so on);

```
private static void MakeConversion(UnitConverter customConverter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of {0} to be converted to {1}.",customConverter.From, customConverter.To);
            double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            string message = string.Format("{0} {1} to said number of {2}", amount, customConverter.To, customConverter.From);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
```

and now you can remove ALL of your methods and in if blocks you can call this one method, just with different parameters instead of calling different methods, which do the same.

else if(type == "miles")
            {
                 MakeConversion(milesToFeetConverter);
            }

After all these manipulation your solution will look like:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class UnitConverter
    {
        double ratio;
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public UnitConverter(double unitratio) { ratio = unitratio; }
        public double Convert(double unit) { return unit * ratio; }
    }

    class Test
    {
        private static void MakeConversion(UnitConverter customConverter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of {0} to be converted to {1}.",customConverter.From, customConverter.To);
            double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            string message = string.Format("{0} {1} to said number of {2}", amount, customConverter.To, customConverter.From);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {                 
            UnitConverter feetToInchesConverter = new UnitConverter(12) { From = "feet", To = "inches"};
            UnitConverter milesToFeetConverter = new UnitConverter(5280) { From = "miles" , To = "feet"};
            UnitConverter kmsToMilesConverter = new UnitConverter(1.609) { From = "kilometers", To = "miles"};
            UnitConverter centToInchesConverter = new UnitConverter(2.54) { From = "centimeters", To = "inches" };
            UnitConverter ozToGramsConverter = new UnitConverter(28.349) { From = "ounces", To = "grams" };
            UnitConverter cupsTolitConverter = new UnitConverter(4.226) { From = "cups", To = "litters" };

            string type;
            int done;

            done = 0;

            while(done == 0)
            {
                {
                    type = Console.ReadLine();

                    if(type == "centi")
                    {
                        MakeConversion(centToInchesConverter);
                    }

                    else if(type == "feet")
                    {
                        MakeConversion(feetToInchesConverter);
                    }

                    else if(type == "km")
                    {
                        MakeConversion(kmsToMilesConverter);
                    }

                    else if(type == "miles")
                    {
                        MakeConversion(milesToFeetConverter);
                    }

                    else if(type == "grams")
                    {
                        MakeConversion(ozToGramsConverter);
                    }

                    else if(type == "cups")
                    {
                        MakeConversion(cupsTolitConverter);
                    }

                    else if(type == "end")
                    {
                        done = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of curce you can do more a lot of things to make code easier and clearer. Replace if with cases, replace `MakeConversion` method directly to UnitConverter class, change architecture of your class. It is only my suggestions about what you can do. But first of all try to learn how to write your oun methods and classes, and don't use VisualStudio method generator, you should know how to write methods yourself. I somehow tried to explain that, hope it helped

Comment: Dang that was helpful, thanks, it also cleared up a bit of wondering on my part if I was actually doing things as simply as possible. Though I do have a question, why the (Get; Set;) arguments inside the string declarations? What do they do? I'm not finding explanations about them them in the language reference.

Comment: They are called `Getter` and `Setter`. You could just create `public string From;` field without get and set methods, but in that case, when you call `message.From` or set to it some value you are calling directly value of class field, but it is not good in terms of class security. When you use `public string From {get; set;}` compiler creates virtual class private field, and get and set functions of this class, which are calling value of this virtual field.

Comment: Though field is private and unaccessible from external classes, but get and set methods of your class, can provide to external classes nessesery acces level, which you can manualy set, for example:  Using getter and setter you can manually `say` that you want just get the value of this property, and forbid it's setting. `public string From {get; private set;}`.

Comment: Or vice versa - you can forbid external classes to get your From property value, and allow them only setting. And use it's value, setted somhere outside it's native class, only inside that class.Or implement your own get logic of this property. `public string From {get { return _somePrivateField.ToLowerCase()}}`.  When you design you application architecture you should pay attention on such things, but considering that you are beginner, it is not the most priority stuff.

Comment: All I wanted to say is creating only field, as it is `double ratio;` in your example doesn't give such possibilities, as properties. (When it is just `double ratio;` - it is called field... When it is `double ratio {get;set;}`) - it is property.

Comment: Thanks again for that explanation. I'm basically rewriting this program from scratch with the advice of the people here.

Answer (score 4):

I ran your code and (after fixing a simple error) it correctly enters the *else if* that you reference.

You may want to echo back what you type in to make sure you are not mistyping your input.

The error was that you have

> done

on a line by itself.  Presumably you meant to assign a value.

Comment: It was actually something similar, I had split the project and didn't realize the debugger was on the last active file instead of the one that I was working on the time. So it worked, after I figured out that it wasn't actually being run when I tried run it. Thank you all for your help, I will be attempting to move to switches for this as well. As they look somewhat better for what I am doing, if I can figure them out. Also the first time I tried to use it after moving the debugger I realized I had was capitalizing instinctively.

Answer (score 0):

Line 141 of the code you page linked to is this:

```
141 - done
```

You are not going anything with that variable and you do not end with a semi-colon.

*(Since you are not using a Visual Studio editor, i suspect the program was working, then you introduced a compile time error. Now each time you run the program, you are possibly running an older version.
Hopefully, you can download and use Visual Studio Express which will increase learning time and decrease confusion time. Good luck)*

Comment: Valamas, I was going to expand it into a helpful fix but I take your point so have deleted.

Answer (score -1):

If the "If else" doesn't get hit, it means one of two things: Either a previous condition is true, or the condition is false.

The '==' operator is case sensitive when comparing [strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  So be sure to take that into account . It is a more complex topic that will make sense later on as you progress.

Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

My suggestion: use Nunit and write an unit test for it. Nunit will give expected and actual value and you'll see why this isn't working.

Comment: Your suggestion for someone who has clearly just started programming is to begin unit testing and learning a framework? How will that help if they don't have the basic fundamentals?

Comment: Thiago, the problem is a compile error. That is not solved by unit testing.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the problem was the comparisson =(